# Jackson disable typing for typed annotated classes

Tags: java, jackson

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "class")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Rabbit.class) })
abstract class Animal {
}

class Rabbit {
}
```

When serializing I usually need the type, hence the annotations.
I have a use case where I would like to serialize but without the type property. I don't want to make use of DTOs. I can't modify the annotations.

I tried to find an option in the `ObjectMapper` class to overwrite these annotations, but without success.

```
ObjectMapper serializer = new ObjectMapper();
serializer.deactivateDefaultTyping();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is through a mixin.

Here's an example:

```
public class TestMe2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper1.writeValueAsString(new Rabbit()));


        ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper2.addMixIn(Animal.class, NoTypes.class);
        System.out.println(mapper2.writeValueAsString(new Rabbit()));
    }

    static class Rabbit extends Animal {
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "class")
    abstract static class Animal {
        public String name = "example";

    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
    class NoTypes {
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh didn't think about using a mixin that way, that's great.  
In case of nested types, we need to configure the same mixin multiple times right?

Comment: The example above shows that it inherits, so you can do it either way :)

Comment: Nice and simple solution.

Comment: @JustinGrant what I meant is when you have: 

class Rabbit {
  Animal animal;
  Human human; // which is also abstract - with types info
}

Comment: I believe (though you would have to test) that it replaces the annotation on the class directly.  So it all depends on the class that you have annotated and your hierarchy.  If you had a Human subclass of an Animal class, I believe it would override for all subclasses. You should be able to give it a try pretty easily with the code above to test it out though.